# Javascript recursive function for banner pictures

Tags: javascript, html

I  trying to create a rotating banner for cycle a few images.

```
const images = [url1, url2 url3]
const rotate = (url) => {
    document.getElementById('banner').style.background = url
    rotate(next)
}
```

Url's are correct full paths only shortened here in question. I'm striggl ing to solve how to get next in code above. This is some code I write from looking at examples. Im not a js programmer only recently started. Thank you for helping.

Comment: Just use a variable to indicate which element in `images` you're on?  You also seem to be missing some semi-colons in your code.  And missing a delay, so I imagine this would just lock the browser?  And why is this recursive?  Won't this just lock up the browser until the stack overflows?

Comment: You want a banner who display img in a delay ?

Comment: @David semicolons are optional in JavaScript, depending on the standard followed.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one approach:

```
const rotate = (element, delay, urls) => {
    let current = 0;
    (function next() {
        element.style.background = url[current]; // set image
        current = (current + 1) % urls.length;   // update for next pass
        setTimeout(next, delay);                 // recycle
    })();                                        // start immediately
};
```

with usage:

```
rotate(document.getElementById('banner'), 5000, [url1, url2, url3]);
```

The modulo arithmetic resets `current` to zero after the last image has been shown.